# Is it possible to escape a fight without fuel?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I am stuck in a never-ending fight in FTL. Is it possible to escape the fight?

I have no fuel, and no missiles left. My shield and my engine are top notch. The enemy shield has 3 slots. My best beam cannot pierce through shields with 2 slots or more. My best laser shoots 2 bullets at a time. The enemy rooms have no oxygen, so any teleportation for a sabotage would lead to the death of my crew.

[image: FTL never-ending fight]

Comment: I know it doesn't help in this case, but if you plan on using the teleporter often in a particular game, get a second power bar for it as soon as you can. you will then have enough time to teleport people back from a deoxygenated ship before they choke

Comment: @Robotnik: Teleport _anyone but a zoltan_ back before they choke.

Comment: This game produces some interesting situations at times, but this one so far is the most odd one yet that I've seen. It would have been amusing if you were in fact locked in endless battle for eternity.

Comment: I had a very similar case with the first Engi ship. I had Ion blasters only, zero droids and no fuel. The battle would go on forever. I had to restart. Your teleporters and hull weapons change the whole story of course.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't be able to escape a situation like this, but your halberd beam should be able to do 1 point of damage per room through a 1 bubble shield, which is what the enemy will have immediately after your hull laser hits. You can destroy the enemy and be on your merry way.

Comment: Yep. The key here is turning off Autofire and carefully timing the weapons.

Comment: Another alternative would have been maximum power to the teleport room and keeping a hawk eye on your people's health. Port into the shield generator, start them punching stuff, port them back out once their health drops past safe level and shoot through the reduced shields.

Comment: @Shadur: Not generally possible with only one bar; not even possible with two bars with a zoltan crew. In this case it would also only reduce their shields from 3 to 2, which still wouldn't help unless wok was timing his shots correctly.

Comment: (And if you send over the engi, I'm not sure it'll do any damage before you have to teleport it out.)

Comment: That said, you might want to use this opportunity to cross-train your crew before you move on.

Answer (score 6):

While [kotezot's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/100392/11311) is the best course of action, there is an ugly alternative.

Sacrifice a crew member.  Teleport them over to start destroying the shield generator.  Then do everything you can with your other weapons to bring it and keep it offline.  Crystals, Mantes and Rockmen are best suited for this task with their improved attacks or protection.  Humans and Slugs can do some damage, but won't live to return.  A single Zoltan or Engi won't do enough damage before suffocating.

Unfortunately, you'd have to expend two crew members to pull this off, leaving you in a dire situation.

This reminds me of an episode of [Start Trek: TNG, Thine Own Self](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_(episode)).

> On the Enterprise, Troi asks Commander Riker if she is allowed to take the Bridge Officer's Test. Riker wonders why, and is told that she has considered it off and on for over two years, but was motivated by her class reunion, as well as being in charge during the events of Disaster. She is allowed to take the test and does so at the holodeck.
>
> Geordi La Forge and Worf are the senior officers in the simulation, where the insulation of the antimatter chambers is breaking down. Troi has to make fast decisions, but fails. Riker tells her that all parts of the test went well for her, except for that last and most important part of it, resulting in Troi failing the whole test.
>
> After having entered the holodeck, Troi starts the test's simulation again. She is in engineering, and the antimatter is about to leak out of its container. She asks La Forge if he can repair the damaged parts. The Worf hologram says that La Forge never will survive the operation, but Troi, well aware of this, orders the holographic La Forge to repair the damage anyway. As an anguished Troi watches him enter the turbolift, Riker, having known she would not give up so easily, enters and congratulates her on passing the test. She immediately deduces that the point of the test was to see if she could order someone to their death, which Riker confirms. Having known this was part of being in command, but having still hesitated when the time came, Troi admits that he may have been right about her being ill-suited for the job - to which Riker counters that she passed with flying colors; she had tried every possible solution she could think of, and when nothing else worked, she made the painful but necessary decision required to save the ship.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. It's a terrible answer generally, but it's an even more terrible answer in this situation, since engi can't do damage, zoltan can't survive long, and even if you knocks the shield down a bubble _you still need to correctly time the attacks to do damage_.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure both Zoltan and Engi crewmembers would die before taking down even one tick of shield bubble - and pilotless ships have some sort of intrinsic self-repair even if you somehow manage it.

Comment: Fair enough.  I wasn't aware of those race's limited combat ability.  For other situations, would you say that sacrificing a crew member could never make the difference in what is otherwise a stalemate?  I'm trying to answer knowing that SX is a site for answers for everyone, not just a single person's specific case.

Comment: I doubt there's any situation where beaming over a crew member to a certain death is a good move. The same is not true about repairs, but the question is not about repairs. Nor is it about a ship that has 6 rock crew. Answers should be about _this question_ (e.g. beam and lasers and zoltan crew), not general playing advice.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig there's nothing much wrong with addressing the general case - SE is about questions and answers that help everybody in a similar situation. I doubt many people will find themselves in a situation that is in every way the same as the OP's. That said, this answer could stand to be improved by taking the other comments into account.